# Enabling billing in Google-map Platform

Tags: google-maps

I had made a billing account in which google cloud platform is enabled and want to change it to google maps platform. I have not used a single credit in that platform. What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

If you are referring to the Google Maps Platform launch in India where you need to have a billing account specific for your Google Maps API usage, currently there is no way to change your billing account from a Google Cloud billing account to a Google Maps specific billing account. You need to create a new billing account that is compatible to Google Maps. You can find the steps to create a Google Maps specific billing account here: https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-india-faq#bill-how

For more information regarding this, you may checkout this link: https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-india-faq

And if you need further assistance with this issue, it would be best for you to reach out to Google Maps Platform support here: https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/support.

Hope this helps.